# ansible commands run only with absolute path

Tags: python, ubuntu, ansible

On **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS** there is ansible engine installed with pip3 command:

```sh
mariusz@g3:~$ pip3 show ansible
Name: ansible
Version: 4.1.0
```

However running ansible commands ends with below error:

```sh
mariusz@g3:~$ ansible
python3: can't open file '/usr/bin/ansible': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The *PATH* variable is set correctly:

```sh
mariusz@g3:~$ which ansible
/home/mariusz/.local/bin/ansible
```

And I can run ansible command with **absolute path**:

```sh
mariusz@g3:~$ /home/mariusz/.local/bin/ansible --version
ansible [core 2.11.1] 
  config file = /home/mariusz/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/mariusz/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/mariusz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/mariusz/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/mariusz/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, May 27 2021, 13:30:53) [GCC 9.3.0]
  jinja version = 2.11.3
  libyaml = True
```

Any ideas how to solve it without root privileges i.e. creating `/usr/bin/ansible` symlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ansible package, which was installed before, left **bash aliases** file that was not removed during package uninstall.

```sh
$ cat ~/.bash_aliases 
alias ansible='python3 /usr/bin/ansible'
alias ansible-doc='python3 /usr/bin/ansible-doc'
alias ansible-galaxy='python3 /usr/bin/ansible-galaxy'
alias ansible-inventory='python3 /usr/bin/ansible-inventory'
alias ansible-playbook='python3 /usr/bin/ansible-playbook'
alias ansible-vault='python3 /usr/bin/ansible-vault'
```

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution; be aware that you can accept your own answer, to let others know you no longer need help

Answer (score 0):

The entries in the `$PATH` variable are tried in order, and thus you'd want to relocate your `$HOME/.local/bin` to the beginning of the list in order for it to win out over the `/usr/bin` entry that's there now

You can do this in an interactive shell to confirm or deny the theory, and then put at the end of your `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent

```sh
PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Directories order in PATH is correct, .local/bin is the first.
The problem was in bash aliases, see the answer.